# not equal constraint for an array of var float decision variables in minizinc

Tags: minizinc

I have a model that needs to constrain each element of a var float array to be alldifferent

I tried to use the global alldifferent global constraint but I get the following error:

```
MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: `alldifferent(array[int] of var float)'
```

So I replaced the alldifferent constraint with the following comprehension:

```
constraint forall (i,j in 1..nVERTICIES where i<j) (X[i] != X[j]);
```

but now I get the following error when I use the Geocode solver:

```
Error: Registry: Constraint float_lin_ne not found
```

and the following error when I use the G12 MIP solver:

```
flatzinc: error: the built-in operation `float_lin_ne/3' is not supported by the MIP solver backend.
```

Is there a different way I can encode this constraint?

Comment: I'm surprised that the current encoding doesn't work. Are you sure you are using the MiniZinc libraries corresponding with the solvers? An alternative is to use `X[i] < Y[i] \/ X[i] > Y[i]`, although this will definitely slow down your model. I would recommend having a good look at your model, it is very uncommon to use `alldifferent` on floats. Are you sure you are not looking for something like the `increasing` or `decreasing` constraint?

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem: acording to the [official documentation](http://www.minizinc.org/doc-lib/doc-globals-alldifferent.html), MiniZinc does not support alldifferent float. Only ints are supported.

For your second problem and third problem: Your solvers does not seam to support floats. Maybe you are not using the letest solvers and/or latest MiniZinc?

Another better solution is to convert your float problem into a integer problem. Just map your floating point range to a integer range instead.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other responses have mentioned there's not (to my knowledge) an `alldifferent` for floats.

Your expression of this global constraint as a series of binary inequalities is a valid approach however the issue you are encountering is a reflection of the difficulty of determining whether two floats are different (which is a broader issue that isn't just limited to CP modelling).

One solution you could do is to compare the absolute difference between your variables and enforce that this must be greater than some configurable value.

```
int: nVERTICES = 10;
float: epsilon = 0.001; % the minimum floats need to be apart to be considered not equal.

array[1..nVERTICES] of var -10.0..10.0: X;
constraint forall (i, j in 1..nVERTICES where i < j) (abs(X[i] - X[j]) >= epsilon);

solve satisfy;

output [ show(X) ];
```

Notice also that I've set a domain on `X` rather than just declaring it as a float. I was experiencing as an `Gecode: Float::linear: Number out of limits` until I switched to specifying the domain explicitly.